# Spark : How to speed rdd.count()

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have streaming application which has count action

```
tempRequestsWithState is a DStream

tempRequestsWithState.foreachRDD { rdd =>

    print (rdd.count())

}
```

The count action is taking a lot of time and **slow taking about 30 mins** Would greatly appreciate if anyone could suggest a way to speedup this action as we are consuming @ **10,000 events/sec** Also noticed we have 54 partitions for each RDD

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: you could use `rdd.countApprox` and make sure the partitioning of your `RDD` is reasonable

Comment: @RaphaelRoth could you please provide more details on rdd.countApprox   i know its syntax is countApprox(timeout=800, confidence=0.5) what does timeout stand for and what does the confidence stand for ?

Comment: Why did you repost this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639455/spark-how-to-speed-up-rdd-count

Comment: Is probably not the count but the transformations you do to get the tempRequestsWithState. You can try the count on original DStream to confirm.

Comment: @PatRoX as per the spark UI from the image posted in the question looks like it is .....rest of all the stages are executing within 30s..please let me know if u need more info

Comment: Count itself can't be slow unless (1) you have a lot of data and a small cluster (not the case here, even with 1 executor should be fast) or (2) getting the data from upstream is slow and in reality that count stage executes other transformations. You should be able to check what exactly gets executed as part of that count stage in Spark UI by expanding the DAG. As I mentioned before, try doing the count on the DStream earlier in the transformation chain, right after getting the data from the input stream (kafka, files, etc.), before the updateState, etc. and move it down until it gets slow.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have never used it, you could try to use `countApprox` on your `RDD`. This seems to give you an estimate of the true count for a given time you want to spend (milliseconds) and a confidence interval (i.e. the probabilty that the true value is within that range):

example usage:

```
val cntInterval = df.rdd.countApprox(timeout = 1000L,confidence = 0.95)
val (lowCnt,highCnt) = (cntInterval.initialValue.low, cntInterval.initialValue.high)
```